# Inverse matrix of a matrix of special structure

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I need to find the inverse of a quadratic matrix $n \times n$ whose elements are all $1$s, except the antidiagonal elements which are all $-1$s.
Is there any special approach that can be applied to this matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Write it as a rank-one update to $-2J$, where $J$ is the [reversal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix). Then apply [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: What is a rank-one update? I read about the reversal matrix.

Comment: So, should I represent my matrix as identity matrix plus a product of some $v$ and $u^T$ as it is given in Wikipedia for Sherman-Morrison formula?

Comment: Thank you. Am I right that the inverse of $J$ is itself? And vectors $u$ and $v$ contain all 1s.

Comment: @user_0_1_2 Yes, but note that the inverse of $-2J$ is not itself, but $-J/2$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thank you so much!!!